# How to use sed to replace the matching character in middle of string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have an XML file "datasources.xml"

```
<item-map group="org.base" datasource="localderby"/>
<item-map group="org.base.pos" datasource="localderbypos"/>
<item-map group="org.base.hr" datasource="localderbyhr"/>
```

and need the output similar to this

```
<item-map group="org.base" datasource="localpostgres"/>
<item-map group="org.base.pos" datasource="localpostpos"/>
<item-map group="org.base.hr" datasource="localposthr"/>
```

So I have been produced the output by command

> sed -e 's/datasource="localderby"/datasource="localpostgres"/g' -e 's/datasource="localderby([a-z])*"/datasource="localpost*/g'  datasources.xml

By the first expression I've got what I want "localpostgres" but the second expression is missing. Anybody can help ,please advices? Thanks forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use extended regexps (`sed -r`) and `+` instead of `*`, and grouping:

```
sed -r -e 's/datasource="localderby"/datasource="localpostgres"/g' -e 's/datasource="localderby([a-z]+)"/datasource="localpost\1"/g' datasources.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to Cadrain why I missed a simple things.